# django many-to-many model simple logic

Tags: python, database, django, django-models, foreign-key-relationship

i am trying to understand this manytomany-field logic in django models.

i have two django models: `location` and `image`.

and i have another third django model named `location_has_image`. this model is defined in this form.

```
class location_has_image(models.Model):
  of_location = models.ForeignKey(location,related_name="of_location")
  of_image = models.ForeignKey(image,related_name="of_image")
```

my question is, do i have to save something into this model when i save new `location` and `image` object? or will this `location_has_image` be automatically set to those newly created objects? or am i thinking in a wrong way here?

please help!

Comment: does that ``add`` do what i want here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use *ManyToManyField* instead. It creates the intermediary join table for you and manages it.

Examples from Django docs:

```
from django.db import models

class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('title',)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.headline

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('headline',)
```

Example:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Field docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#ref-manytomany

Comment: thanks. so, then i dont need that ``location_has_image`` model, right? instead, i will make one ``image`` field to manytomanyfield which refers to location, right?

Comment: i think, my case should be more ``oneToMany`` because one location can have multiple images, and multiple images belong to one location, right?

Comment: If an image is only related to one location then you do not need either an intermediary table or the ManyToManyField. Just use ForeignKey field on the image.

Comment: Feel free to post another question or an update with a more detailed model and I'll be happy to review it.